# Iterate through Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe based on this data:

```
np.random.seed(1111)
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Category':np.random.choice( ['Group A','Group B'], 10000),
'Sub-Category':np.random.choice( ['X','Y','Z'], 10000),
'Sub-Category-2':np.random.choice( ['G','F','I'], 10000),
'Product':np.random.choice( ['Product 1','Product 2','Product 3'], 10000),
'Units_Sold':np.random.randint(1,100, size=(10000)),
'Dollars_Sold':np.random.randint(100,1000, size=10000),
'Customer':np.random.choice(pd.util.testing.rands_array(10,25,dtype='str'),10000),
'Date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2016','12/31/2018',  
                      freq='D'), 10000)})
```

I then create a groupby to format my data as I'd like:

```
sales = df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month,'Customer','Product'])['Units_Sold','Dollars_Sold'].sum()
```

I'd like to iterate through this groupby to write each 'Customer' to it's own Excel workbook with the file being saved as 'Customer'.xlsx. Inside each workbook for each customer, I'd like to have each 'Date' (aka Month) write to it's own worksheet.

Here is an example of a loop I'm currently using to write each customer to it's own sheet:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for c in sales.index.get_level_values(1).unique():
    sales.loc[idx[:,c,:],idx[:]]\
    .to_excel(writer, sheet_name=c)
writer.save()
```

I have found a way to write each to it's own sheet inside a workbook, but can't seem to put it all together. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try making the 'Customer' the first item in your groupby list.  This will make things easier.

Comment: Hi Chris - thanks for taking the time to respond. That's not an issue & is easy enough to do just by swapping the order in the groupby. I'm looking for more of the methodology behind it all as there are many examples where I'd use this type of code in the future. Thanks again for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  I essentially reset the index on the sales groupby object to get a regular dataframe.  Take the unique list of customers from the customer column.  Iterate over the list of customers, making a dataframe for each customer.

Group that by the date, then iterate over the groupby object using d, s where d = date, and s = sales.

Use string formatting to enter the customer id as the workbook name, and use str(d) as the sheet name.  Use pandas to_excel to write the sheets within the workbook and save the finished workbook at the end of each iteration of the loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1111)
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Category':np.random.choice( ['Group A','Group B'], 10000),
'Sub-Category':np.random.choice( ['X','Y','Z'], 10000),
'Sub-Category-2':np.random.choice( ['G','F','I'], 10000),
'Product':np.random.choice( ['Product 1','Product 2','Product 3'], 10000),
'Units_Sold':np.random.randint(1,100, size=(10000)),
'Dollars_Sold':np.random.randint(100,1000, size=10000),
'Customer':np.random.choice(pd.util.testing.rands_array(10,25,dtype='str'),10000),
'Date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2016','12/31/2018',  
                      freq='D'), 10000)})

sales = df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month,'Customer','Product'])['Units_Sold','Dollars_Sold'].sum().reset_index()

customers = sales['Customer'].unique()

for customer in customers:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('{}.xlsx'.format(customer), engine='xlsxwriter')
    temp = sales[sales['Customer'] == customer]
    temp = temp.drop(columns='Customer')
    temp = temp.groupby('Date')
    for d, s in temp:
        s.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(d), index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works exactly as I had hoped. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I tried this with my own data - it works great! Thanks so much. Now my dilemma is I'm looking to add in formatting using Xlsxwriter. I have many new workbooks & worksheets created & to manually format is difficult. Do you have any tips in the loop as to where to place something like 'worksheet.set_column('B:C', 20) to set the column width of columns B & C for example?

Comment: Add all of your formatting just prior to the writer.save() line.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I was trying to add it inside the second for loop & it wasn't working as anticipated. Made it harder than it needed to be - thanks!